# Error while trying to set custom AWSTraceHeader when sending a SQS message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

My architecture is built like this:
I have a Lambda (let's call it `l1`), that sends messages to a SQS, and other lambda (let's call it `l2`) that listen to this queue.
I am trying to set a custom `AWSTraceHeader` when sending a SQS, using boto3.
The message contains the following attributes:

```py
class SqsMessage(pydantic.BaseModel, ABC):
    Id: str
    MessageBody: str
    MessageAttributes: Optional[Dict[str, MessageAttributeValueTypeDef]]
    MessageSystemAttributes: Optional[Dict[str, MessageAttributeValueTypeDef]]
    MessageGroupId: Optional[str]
    MessageDeduplicationId: Optional[str]
```

And in `MessageSystemAttributes` I put:

```py
MessageSystemAttributes={'AWSTraceHeader': 'Root=...'}
```

When I send a custom message (via integration test) to `l1` for the **first** time, then the message is fine. But when this message reaches from the SQS to `l2`, then there's an error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendMessageBatch operation: The message system attribute 'AWSTraceHeader' is reserved for AWS X-Ray trace header. Value '...' is invalid.
```

<s>But when I send the same message for the second time, when the lambdas are running (and not in the cold start phase), then I don't get this error.</s>

I have already tried using AWS' guide to create the correct code, using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-traceids) guide.

I have already tried to set the tracer head to the correct format using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-traceids) guide, without any luck.
I have also tried sending it multiple times, but this error occurs only for the first run, when the lambda is cold.

EDIT:
It happens on every run, not only in the first run. It happened only in the first run because I accidentally added the wrong assertion in the integration test, that made me think that it worked correctly.

EDIT 2:
The message that received in the lambda (`l1`) is this: `{..., "AWSTraceHeader":"Root=...;Sampled=1"`, and sending the message: `self._queue.send_messages(Entries=messages_dict_list)` where `self._queue` is:

```py
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
self._queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)
```

`messages_dict_list` is `[message.dict(exclude_none=True for message in messages]`. The messages are built the same way I wrote above - as `SqsMessage`.

Comment: You definitely need to set a valid format to get rid of this error message. That this only occurs on cold starts indicates that the problem is in another location and you need to show us more of your Lambda code.

Comment: In that case we're back to you not setting valid tracing-headers. Please review the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-traceids) about the format and note the Python code example. It would help a lot if you could show more of the code that produces the errors, this is not enough to debug that behavior.

Comment: The message that received in the lambda (`l1`) is this:
`{..., "AWSTraceHeader":"Root=...;Sampled=1",`
and sending the message:
`self._queue.send_messages(Entries=messages_dict_list)`
where `self._queue` is:
`sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
    self._queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)`

Comment: `messages_dict_list` is `[message.dict(exclude_none=True for message in messages]`.
The messages are built the same way I wrote above - in `SqsMessage`